# Where does Atom (or it's installed packages) store debug log files?

Tags: debugging, atom-editor, logfile

I just opened [this bug report](https://github.com/ditinc/linter-cflint/issues/24) on github.  Obviously it would be nice to add some detail from the log file.

Where does Atom store them?  Is this error referring to perhaps a log file generated by the package itself?  If so, is there a conventional directory location for package log files, or would a package write to a main/shared Atom log file?

Comment: Reason for downvote?  I'd love to improve the question if possible.

Answer (score 8):

The error [gets logged](https://github.com/ditinc/linter-cflint/blob/master/lib/main.js#L127) to the Atom console (`View > Developer > Toggle Developer Tools`). If you want to preserve it in future session, you need activate the *Preserve log* checkbox at the top of the panel:

[image]

Comment: Ah, good to know.  The message did say `log file`, so I'm wondering if there's a file on the filesystem somewhere that is created or appended to in addition to something like this.